# T-Invariant- How to start?

Tags: linear-algebra, invariance

Let T be a linear endomorphism on a vector space V . Now I must show
that a subspace W is T-invariant, if and only if it is (T − λI)-invariant. Here we say λ is some number.

So I know with T-Invariance that T(W)⊂W, but I have to show that this is true, only if it is "(T − λI)-invariant".

Right now I thought of defining the subspace W such that $ W=Span (v_1,v_2,...,v_m) $ so by the problem (T − λI)(W)⊂W? I'm wondering if my train of thought here is correct and how to really start this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take $\;w\in W\;$ , then if $\;W\;$ is $\;T\,-$ invariant, then for any scalar$\;\lambda\;$:

$$(T-\lambda I)w=Tw-w\in W\;,\;\;\text{since}\;\;Tw\in W$$

Try now to do the reverse deduction. If you understood the above is almost trivial.

Comment: Because it says if and only if, the reverse would be if it is not (T − λI)-invariant.

$(T−λI)w≠ Tw−w$ But then that would mean Tw∉W? Does that make a contradiction then? If I'm understanding this correctly ?

Comment: What you wrote is the contrapositive of what I wrote, meaning: the same. You must now prove that if $\;W\;$ is $\;(T-\lambda I)\,-$ invariant, then it is $\;T\,-$ invariant.

Comment: Ah I see, I have to prove the other way around is true.

If I take $w-I∈W$, then if W is (T−λI)-invariant, then for any scalarλ:

$T(w-I)=Tw-w ∈W, since Tw ∈ W$ So W is T-Invariant? 

I'm not sure if that is necessarily correct as I let  $w-I∈W$ to kind of force my proof...

Comment: No. If we take $\;w\in W\;$ ...and etc. The expression $\;w-I\;$ doesn't even make sense.

Comment: Yea I only did that to get the formula $T(w−I)=Tw−w$ and make my proof easy. No shortcuts though is what I'm learning from linear algebra.